# Post query to API in Django REST

Tags: django, angular, rest, django-rest-framework

I have code in Angular 2:

```
sendPost(){
    let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    requestOptions.headers = headers;

      let data = {
                  "name": "XX", 
                  "email": "xxx@op.com", 
                  "phone_number": "+99999995555", 
                  "address": "YYY", 
                  "code": "80-885", 
                  "city": "YHYY", 
                  "voivodeship": "ZZZZ", 
                  "description": "VVVVV"
                  };

        this.http.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/create`, data, requestOptions).subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res.json());
          }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
  }
```

Error API:

```
<WSGIRequest: OPTIONS '/companies/create'>
Internal Server Error: /companies/create
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:XX\CRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:XX\CRM\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 198, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view my_crm.views.companies_create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[25/Jul/2017 21:32:35] "OPTIONS /companies/create HTTP/1.1" 500 59515
```

The API shows that there is an error somewhere in the function but when I use POSTMAN this is identical JSON goes through with no problem. Where can be the error?
I think the API is well handled when testing using POSTMAN.

**EDIT:**
API function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def companies_create(request):
    """
    Create a new company.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CompanySerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: post a api view function please

Comment: @Aniket I added

Comment: Your http method is OPTION `WSGIRequest: OPTIONS`, but you response only if the method POST

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

to:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

I'm not able to explain this because I'm sending a JSON file. Maybe someone will explain what this is about?